# Difference between installing libx:i386 and lib32x

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries, multiarch

There's a series of libs available in the Ubuntu repositories like `lib32stdc++6` and `lib32ncurses5`. You can either install these on a 64 bit system, or go for installing `libstdc++6:i386` and `libncurses5:i386`. I'm interested to learn what the difference is between the two types of packages.

What is the actual difference? Why are they both available?
Being under the impression that `libx:i386` is the new way of doing things, is this method always preferred over installing the `lib32x` variant?
Having a couple of `lib32x` and a couple of `libx:i386` libraries already installed also makes me wonder if it would be a good idea to switch to only one type of package by replacing them with there counterparts.

Comment: Good question. Looks like duplicate packages in the repositories. The only reason I can find for having this is efficient support for both multi-arch enabled systems and requirements for some single-arch enabled systems. However, I think all Ubuntu versions are multi-arch now. By the way, for reference three package links: [libstdc++6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libstdc++6), [lib64stdc++6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/lib64stdc++6), [lib32stdc++6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/lib32stdc++6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical difference between these packages is where the libraries are located. With `libfoo:i386`, libraries end up in multiarch paths such as `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` whereas with `lib32foo:amd64` libraries end up in the "old" paths such as `/usr/lib32`. In a distant future we would get rid of any `lib32foo` packages, but we are not there yet. At least `lib32stdc++6` is needed for building `gcc-X.Y` at the moment, because it builds `gcc-X.Y-multilib` which is capable of supporting switches such as `-m32` to select the target architecture (i.e. the architecture of the resulting binary). Without the `lib32foo` packages, the build-dependencies of `gcc-X.Y` would cross architecture boundaries and this is not yet supported. There are a few more issues that require keeping the `lib32foo` packages for a while.

Comment: If `gcc-X.Y-multilib` is an exception requiring a `lib32foo` package, what about 'general' 32bit applications? Do they care if a library is located in either `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` or `/usr/lib32`?

Comment: Both paths are tried for libraries by binaries. To verify that look at `/etc/ld.so.conf` (and the corresponding directory). Multiarch paths take precedence over "old" paths, since the files are considered lexicographically.

Comment: "keeping the lib32foo packages for a while" - still the case 4 years later? :)